# Maximum size of an array in php (Zend)

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

Here is my problem : I have an array of ~200 elements which is saved. The array is defined like this:

```
$my_arr = $this->getAllParams()
```

If I do a print_r of this, all my elements are here (local). But on my server, I can't figure out WHY I don't have all my elements, it finish at the ~150th element, so I can't save it. But If I delete for example 60 elements, the array will have 140 elements.

Maybe I missed something ? I can't post code because this is way too big, but perhaps you have some hints...

Comment: There is no limit to array size, only the execution time limit on some servers.

Comment: Okay thanks !
I also changed it, but still doesn't works :(

Comment: ...and the memory limit, however if either the memory limit or the execution limit are exceeded, the script will abort with an error. It will not fail to load the file.

Comment: Did you check `post_max_size` directive in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

As per comment above, the issue is neither the time not the memory limit. 200 elements in an array shouldn't cause PHP any problems.

Nor is the issue that the file is corrupt - you can easily test this for yourself. If the file is not valid then the unserialize operation will return false and flag a notice. Although it would have been advisable to check if any warnings/notices/errors were being flagged.

> $my_arr = $this->getAllParams()

That's a useless peice of information. All it tells is is that the array comes out of a mystery black box.

Either you are using the wrong file or your code is doing something unexpected.

Comment: I know but I don't think that the problem is in the code, it works well on local and everything works well, except this on server
I'll check for your advice, I'm not a pro but i'll try